# Installing WolframScript (12) on OSX (Catalina)

Tags: scripting, mac-os-x, installation

I did a clean install of Catalina (OSX 10.15) and Mathematica 12.0 installation was flawless. However I can't install WolframScript which I greatly need.

During the installation, after typing my password, I get the follong error:

**This package is incompatible with this version of macOS.**
*The package is trying to install content to the system volume. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.*

And I'm left with only a "Quit" button to click on.

I can't find any mention of this issue on Google or here. Actually Google shows: *No results found for "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS" mathematica.*

Thanks in advance for any help or hint on where/what to look into !

Comment: I had the same issue. I contacted support and they said it's a known issue and an updated release is coming soon.

Comment: The installer from https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/ should work

Comment: Thanks, indeed version 12.0.1 solves the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Download the latest WolframScript installer, which will work on macOS 10.14:

> The installer from [wolfram.com/wolframscript](http://wolfram.com/wolframscript) should work – ilian Oct 25 at 16:10

Comment: In the meantime this has also been fixed in the main installer.

Comment: I think some institutes [might still be distributing the original installer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210594/12), so it's useful to have this answer.