# Catalina is not compatible with WolframScript 12

Tags: mac-os-x, installation

Today, I was trying to install the Mathematica 12 on my MacBook Pro with the latest system Mac OS Catalina v 10.15.1. The installation somehow failed because there appears to be some incompatibility between the system and Mathematica 12. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please take the [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). Mathematica 12.0 works fine on Catalina. Please edit the question and describe the problem precisely, with clear steps on how to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, people won't be able to help.

Comment: The problem appears when I try to ``install" the Mathematica12 provided by my department. The exe file is called Mathematica_12.0.0_MAC_DM.dmg. Also, several weeks ago, I have already received a system warning saying the current version of Mathematica I am using is not optimised for Catalina.

Comment: The description in the question is inaccurate: it is installing WolframScript that fails, not installing Mathematica. Mathematica works fine. See here for a solution for WolframScript: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208418/12

Comment: OK. Thanks for the tips.